How can I end all my active contracts at once on Upwork?
I hire freelancers on Upwork. I finished a large project, and now I'd  like to end all my active contracts at once on Upwork. How can I end all my active contracts at once on Upwork?
I don't want to have to end each contract manually one by one:


Have you tried just asking them?
